# Why can Computer-A see Computer-B's LAN World, but not vice-versa?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with the LAN World feature in Minecraft: Java Edition. When I attempt to share my world with another computer on my network, they cannot see it when they enter multi-player mode.

However, when they try to share their world with me, I can see it an interact with it as expected.

I'm puzzled that my computer can see their LAN World, but they cannot see mine.

What sort of issue does this behavior indicate? Has anyone else experienced it?

I've performed a modest search for this issue on the web and here on SE, but I couldn't find anyone else who reported the same behavior. (It's possible that I wasn't using effective search terms as I'm not even sure if there's a name for the sort of behavior I'm experiencing.)

Comment: Are both instances of Minecraft running the same version? Also, are the firewall/network discovery settings the same for both computers? (I'm assuming they're both Windows PCs, too...)

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, both instances of Minecraft are the same, at least as far as I can tell. For example, I'm can replicate this this behavior with the latest release, i.e., 1.15.2. Each machine is MacBook Pro, although different models, running macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan). I've tweaked Firewall settings to match. By "discovery settings," I assume you mean the Sharing settings. These are turned of on both Macs. (If you meant something else, LMK.)

Comment: Sharing sounds like the same thing; on Windows, there are network discovery options that allow other devices on your network to 'discover' a given device, or prevent them from doing so if the option is turned off.